# ServiceStack Routes and Verbs

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to establish a coding pattern (some rules) in the services we create for our business.
We are following the basic guidance laid out by apigree for designing RESTful services.

One of the rules we would like to adopt is to block certain route and verb combos that we don't want to support. Presumably we would send back a HttpStatusCode.NotSupported for these illegal combos, and perhaps a human readable message?

The legal combos we do want to support are:

```
GET /resource - lists all resources
GET /resource/{id} - retrieves specific resource by ID
POST /resource - adds a new resource 
PUT /resource/{id} - updates specific resource by ID
DELETE /resource/{id} - deletes specific resource by ID
```

There are some illegal combos we explicitly don't want to support.

```
POST /resource
PUT /resource
DELETE /resource
```

We do have validators for each of the supported routes.
But we don't have any of these illegal routes defined anywhere in our codebase.

From testing we have learned that if a client sends a `GET /resource/{id}` request with a blank id (string.Empty), then ServiceStack magic does not execute the validator for that request (`GET /resource/{id}`), but instead redirects to GET /resource. We think it does the same for `DELETE /resource/{id}` and `PUT /resource/{id}`. But none of these 'default' behaviours is desirable, we would rather want to return a HttpStatusCode.NotSupported or with some header directing client to API documentation (or some such guidance).

Could you suggest some options to handle these cases explicitly in the framework?

cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want to allow certain calling conventions than you should be explicit in what you allow with the Route definitions, e.g:

```
[Route("/resource", "GET")]
public class GetAllResources {}

[Route("/resource/{Id}", "GET")]
public class GetResource 
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
}

[Route("/resource", "POST")]
public class CreateResource { ... }

[Route("/resource/{Id}", "PUT")]
public class UpdateResource 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

[Route("/resource/{Id}", "DELETE")]
public class DeleteResource 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Than in your Service only match the Verbs you've specified:

```
public class ResourceServices : Service
{
    public object Get(GetResources request) { ... }
    public object Get(GetResource request) { ... }
    public object Post(CreateResource request) { ... }
    public object Put(UpdateResource request) { ... }
    public object Delete(DeleteResource request) { ... }
}
```

What's not matched will simply be a **404 NotFound**, because there are no matching routes that will handle the request.

Otherwise you can create services to specifically catch illegal requests and treat them as you wish, e.g:

```
[Route("/resource", "DELETE PUT")]
public class IllegalActions {}

public class ResourceServices : Service
{
    public object Any(IllegalActions request) 
    {
        return new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "ActionNotSupported");
    }
}
```

The [Error Handling wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling) does a good job at showing all the Error customizations available in ServiceStack. Being able to map C# Exceptions to Http Status Codes may also be useful here:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig { 
    MapExceptionToStatusCode = {
        { typeof(NotImplementedException), (int)HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable },
        { typeof(NotSupportedException), (int)HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable },
    }
});
```

Comment: Problem is that your solution is exactly what we have (except that our Id field is a string not an int). The issue is that when we call GET /resource/{Id} and the ID is blank (i.e. string.Empty) SS redirects the call to Get /resource, not 404, or any other validation. There is some magic at work here. We need to control it.

Comment: @JezzSantos Do you mean `GET /resource/` redirects? that would be ASP.NET doing the redirecting not ServiceStack. So don't rely on the difference between `GET /resource` and `Get /resource/`, they both should mean the same thing, i.e. GET all resources.

Comment: Ah! thank you that makes sense. I guess there must be some kind of Trim() going on somewhere at the end of the route perhaps?